# Am having issues updating records in laravel. How do i fix it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Am working on a simple project in Laravel and am having issues updating records relating to undefined variable. which i think i have. I have a table with edit button which redirects to update.blade.php on click. The error message am receiving is from and undefined variable connected to the DB or something. Please how do i fix this issue? I need assistance

Please this is the error message am receiving.

[image]

This is the **update.blade.php** file

```
@extends('layout.app')



@section('content')


<h1>Update</h1>


<form method="post" action="/users">

{{!!csrf_field()!!}}

   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Name</label>
   <input type="text" value="{!! $message->name !!}"  name="name" class="form-control" required>
   </div>

   <div class="form-group">
   <label>Email</label>
   <input type="text" value="{!! $message->email !!}"  name="email" class="form-control" required>
   </div>


   {{method_field('PUT')}}

   <button name="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>



</form>




@endsection
```

**MessagesController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Message;

class MessagesController extends Controller
{
    public function submit(Request $request){

        $message = new Message;
        $message -> name = $request -> input('name');
        $message -> email = $request -> input('email');
        $message -> message = $request -> input('message');

        $message -> save();

        return redirect('/') -> with('status', 'Message sent');

            }



    public function getMessages(){

        $message = Message::all();
        return view('messages') -> with('messages', $message);

    }


    public function edit($id){

        $message = Message::find($id);
        if (empty($message)) {
            return redirect('/user');
        }

        return view('update', compact($message));

    }






}
```

Model **Message.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Message extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: You named it `messages`, not `message` on `-> with('messages', $message);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
 public function edit($id){

        $message = Message::find($id);
        if (empty($message)) {
            return redirect('/user');
        }

       return view('update', compact('message'));

    }
```

Comment: :) welcome and then please accept the answer. Thank you.